# How to revoke a bearer token (w/o refresh)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, oauth

Context: Instead of creating refresh tokens for my API, I want to give users a lifetime expiry token for authentication. But let's say a token gets compromised, I need to be able to revoke it. Now OAuth does not support revoking out of the box, so I'm looking for a workaround.

My rough approach:

1. Every API call, check the bearer token. And if it belongs to some blacklist (stored in db) then don't give access to that token. But for this, I need to be able to fetch the token from the caller. Any idea how I can do that? Do I need to modify [System.Web.Http.Authorize] tag somehow?
2. Use https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.owin.security.oauth.oauthbearerauthenticationprovider.onrequesttoken(v=vs.113).aspx to check the validity?

Gist: I need to be able to keep track of which token is used to make calls on any of the action events on my controller.

Thanks.

Comment: Why not use the refresh token which is the "OAuth" method? Why track the token? Why not the user or Client ID?

Comment: doesn't sound like you need Oauth at all. Why do you even bother with it if you want to have your own thing anyway? The OAuth way would be to generate a short lived token and refresh it if you really need to, not one that lasts forever. That's like having lunch on the train line and wondering why you got hit by the train.

Comment: But how do you access a token on the server side?

Answer (score 1):

Surely you are on the right track. 
Each of the request sent to the Api will carry the token information. All you have to do is to extend the current [Authorize] attribute to fetch the token information & validate it.